# Remove Trailing slash from the domain name of the site in drupal 6

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal-6

I am facing 1 problem on my live site.

I am working on the Drupal 6 and its a multilingual site. I have URL like : www.sitename.com/fr and www.sitename.com this two URL for both the languages.

Now when some one write www.sitename.com/fr/ in the address bar of browser it will redirect to the same www.sitename.com/fr/ instead of www.sitename.com/fr.

As we all know this affect a lot for ranking of the site.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule to remove trailing slash **before all other rules in your root .htaccess**:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.